# How to split string by same multiple delimiters in Java

Tags: string, split

I am trying to split the string 'id@namespace' by `@`.

There is this special case that the id has a format `name@gmail` which makes the string I am trying to split look like `name@gmail@namespace`.

Is there any way to achieve that only split by the last `@` which will give me `name@gmail` and `namespace`?

Comment: Did my answer using split work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is always the last index. Use `lastIndex` to find the last index of the character and then use `substring`

Something like this

```
int idx = string.lastIndexOf("@");
String[] splitStrings =  {string.substring(0, idx), string.substring(idx)};
```

Comment: thanks, your solution works as expected if it is string.substring(idx+1). :)

Comment: can we use string.split() to achieve the same behavior?

Comment: @FrancisZhu Unfortunately no. Why do you want to use `split` though ?

Comment: no particular reason, I am just curious if split() can do the same magic. If no, then I will accept your answers

Comment: @FrancisZhu `String.split` has a flavour that can limit the generated tokens `public String[] split(String regex,
             int limit)` However it works like `first occurrence` based unlike the last occurrence you are interested in

Answer (score 0):

You could match the last `@` using a [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?!` to assert that there are no more `@` following:

`@(?!.*@)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DXWZUA/1)

`System.out.println("name@gmail@namespace".split("@(?!.*@)")[0]); //name@gmail`